# I can't install nvidia driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics

When I try to install the graphics driver it shows the following error message. I also tried fixing the broken package but it didn't work.

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-390 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

if this might help, here is some info about my current system

dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

nashib@nashib-Vostro-5470:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

nashib@nashib-Vostro-5470:~$ apt-cache policy nvidia-390 lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
nvidia-390:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1
  Version table:
     390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
lib32gcc1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libc6-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Try different driver version like `nvidia-384`.

Comment: it also shows the same message

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, and `apt-cache policy nvidia-390 lib32gcc1 libc6-i386`? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Software and Updates app. Click on the Other Software tab, check the Canonical Partners checkbox, enter your password when prompted. Then click on Close then on the Reload button. It will update the cache then close. Launch it again, click on the Addition Drivers tab. It will search for any drivers that it can find. If your WiFi adaptor is supported, it will come back with driver options for you to select. Choose one then click on Apply Changes

Comment: i just did it, everything goes fine but when i tried to apply changes after selecting driver, it automatically revert to the default one.